# In Backbone.js, why do silent changes trigger change events eventually?

Tags: backbone.js, backbone-events, backbone-model

When I pass `{"silent":true}` while setting an attribute in a Backbone model, why doesn't that just suppress the `change:attribute` event? What is the advantage of firing that event the next time an attribute is changed?

**Update**

Backbone 0.9.10 changed the behavior of passing `{ "silent": true }`. From the changelog:

> Passing `{silent:true}` on change will no longer delay individual
>   "change:attr" events, instead they are silenced entirely.

Browse the changelog [here](http://backbonejs.org/#changelog)

Answer (score 30, accepted):

This has confused me for some time as well.

The reason is that {silent:true} does **not** mean "Do everything as normal, but just don't trigger the event".

From various comments and answers by @jashkenas, what it seems to mean is "simply change the attribute value (and add it to the 'changedAttributes' hash), but defer all other "change-related" activities until later".

'silent' doesn't *prevent* the `change` event for that/those properties, it simply queues up the 'announcement' until the next `change` event is triggered.

So, its probably better named something like `defer`.

**Relevant information:**

https://github.com/documentcloud/backbone/pull/850

> the point of a "silent" change is that it isn't considered a change from the models point of view. Later, when the change actually occurs, you get the full difference all at once.

https://github.com/documentcloud/backbone/issues/870

> Because the point of silent changes is that you're allowed to twiddle with the internal state of your model, temporarily, without actually making a change. Later, when the attribute actually changes, the validation runs and events are emitted. It wouldn't make sense to emit an error event when making a silent change.

### Update 4/7/2013

*Note: I have not tested this to confirm behavior, this is just based on my reading of the release notes...*

As of Backbone 0.9.10, the behavior described above has changed.  In that version (and newer), `silent:true` suppresses the `change:attr` events entirely - not just delays them.

http://backbonejs.org/#changelog

Comment: Interesting. The reason I want to pass "silent:true" in general is to prevent a change event handler from being called. I wonder if that's a common situation that others would benefit from being able to deal with?

Answer (score 2):

In backbone 0.9.2 the `set` function runs validation before any changes are updated.

```
  // Run validation.
  if (!this._validate(attrs, options)) return false;
```

In case of `{silent: true}` option is passed, the validation code will not be executed.

```
  if (options.silent || !this.validate) return true;
```

That means, `model.set({value: 100}, {silent: true});` is able to set "invalid" value into model, so attributes are updated, but change event's are not firing.

It is useful, then you want to update some field and prevent whole mode validation, so if model is not yet completed, the change still propagated to attributes. But you usually you also want the view to show the change, so you have to manually call `model.change()` or `model.trigger('change:value', model, value)`.

Comment: I want to focus that it would be fine to separate completely the validation and the triggering of the change event. In my widgets, when the user leaves the widget with the mouse (blur), there is no validation (validation is only with TAB or ENTER), but I save the changed value and I want to get informed when this happens (change event triggered) in order to react to that.