# {silent:true} in Backbone 1.0 version

Tags: backbone.js, backbone-events, backbone-model

I was updating my backbone version from 0.9.2 to 1.0 yet I've encountered a problem.

The model is not updating properly. It has delays in it. previously my code below works perfectly:

```
this.model({ attrib: true},{silent:true});
```

But after updating I removed the `{silent:true}` and everything works perfectly. The model updates properly.

I've read something like this on Backbonejs.org

*Passing {silent:true} on change will no longer delay individual "change:attr" events, instead they are silenced entirely.*

I dont get entirely what the statement means.

Comment: possible duplicate of [In Backbone.js, why do silent changes trigger change events eventually?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10030139/in-backbone-js-why-do-silent-changes-trigger-change-events-eventually)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

About the meaning of the doc you quoted:

When you were doing (I guess the `this.model` was an error) `this.set({attr: value}, {silent: true})`, all the change events were just **delayed** until the next non-silent change. That is, if you were doing `this.trigger('change')` (as of the last versions of jQuery/Backbone, `this.change()` doesn't work anymore) or `this.set('anotherAttr', anotherValue)`, a `change:attr` event would have been triggered.

As of Backbone 1.0, this behavior has changed. When you're using the silent flag, you're **not delaying** the `change:attr` event anymore, you're **shutting** it off completely.

So basically, to illustrate with a piece of code:

```
myModel.listenTo(myModel, 'change:attr', function() {alert();});
myModel.set('attr', true, {silent: true});
myModel.trigger('change');
// or myModel.set('anotherAttr', true);
```

will do an alert in Backbone prior 1.0, but not in Backbone 1.0.

Comment: my apologies.. typo. :)

just recently I read this. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10030139/in-backbone-js-why-do-silent-changes-trigger-change-events-eventually and it seems to answer my question. Well also you're answer confirms it. thanks.

Comment: @Dreyfus15 please consider accepting the answer or deleting your question, don't let it in this state while your problem seems solved.

Comment: sorry. I forgot. I was going to mark your answer but it required me to mark your answer after 2hours and it slipped my mind. thanks